# iOS Framework - Loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, ios-frameworks

I saw many questions similar to mine but no solutions worked and this may be because I am creating and then importing an iOS framework into a project.

Basically, I have a **SignIn framework** and I want to show a webview if the user is not signed in.

My normal project will call my framework and if I need to authenticate, the **SignIn framework** will tell me to load a certain .xib to sign in.

In my framework, this .xib is named **SignIn.xib** It contains a view controller with a webview inside as you an see:

[image]

Now, in my framework, I init the view controller and call a function of the delegate to load the signInView:

```
NSString* const frameworkBundleID  = @"iOSLoginSDK";
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:frameworkBundleID];

SignInViewController* signInViewController = [[SignInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignIn" bundle:bundle];

[self.delegate loadSignInView:signInViewController];
```

In my project, I simply do the following and this method will be called by the delagate:

```
-(void) loadSignInView:(CYMSignInViewController *)signInViewController {
     [self presentViewController:signInViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, I have the following error when I try to run the application:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SignIn" nib but the view outlet was not set.
```

I am using **XCode 6.3.2**

**Edit 1: I think the problem happens because I have a view controller inside my xib. Can I do that?**

Edit 2: Here are my outlets in my .xib

[image]

Edit3: I tried to recreate the nib but I still get the same error.

Here are the steps I did:

1. I created an empty xib
2. I added a view controller and then I added my element onto it
3. I created a view controller file and I set it as the custom class of the view controller

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You have a simple error in your nib - the outermost `UIView` needs to be connected to the `view` outlet of your UIViewController object. Simply select the UIView and control-drag to the UIViewController object and select the `view` outlet

Comment: My outermost, do you mean the View Controller since that's what the outermost is or the FileOwner? Because it looks like it is, see edit2

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the left-hand NIB navigator panel that shows the hierarchy of objects?  Files Owner should be your UIViewController class `SignInViewController` - The first object in the actual NIB component hierarchy should be a UIView - this view would contain your toolbar and UIWebView

Comment: I think that's what I have: http://imgur.com/6oE7ViH

Comment: It looks right from the screen shots. It looks like a pretty simple nib - perhaps try re-creating it.

Comment: I recreated it but I still get the same error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you can upload your nib file somewhere I can take a look

Comment: Ok I figured it out, it was really simple, I suppose you can't have a view controller you must only set a view and then set the file's owner custom class to your view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so basically, it seems like you can't have a view controller in a standalone .xib. I think because the .xib is a view controller in a way (someone could clarify).

What I did, is that I created a view, set my design properly and then, I assigned my ViewController class file to the File's owner. That way, it is now working.

Comment: That is how you should do it - sorry, it wasn't clear from your screenshots what you had done.  You can add another UIViewController into a view using a container, but that UIViewController instance is typically associated with its own NIB or Storyboard scene